# Mapping images from object in Vite.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, vite

```js
import React from 'react';
import { ReactComponent as CasesNext } from '../assets/arrow-right.svg';
import { ReactComponent as CasesPrev } from '../assets/arrow-left.svg';

const caseStudies = [
  {
    id: 1,
    subtitle: 'Curology',
    title: "A custom formule for your skin's unique needs",
    img: 'curology-min',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    subtitle: 'YourSpace',
    title: 'Open space plans for your next adventure',
    img: 'yourspace-min',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    subtitle: 'Lumin',
    title: 'For your best look ever',
    img: 'lumin-min',
  },
];

const Cases = () => {
  return (
    <section className='cases'>
      <div className='container-fluid'>
        <div className='cases-navigation'>
          <div className='cases-arrow prev disabled'>
            <CasesPrev className='svg' />
          </div>
          <div className='cases-arrow next'>
            <CasesNext className='svg' />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='row'>
          {caseStudies.map((caseItem) => (
            <div className='case' key={caseItem.id}>
              <div className='case-details'>
                <span>
                  {caseItem.subtitle}
                  <h2>{caseItem.title}</h2>
                </span>
              </div>
              <div className='case-image'>
                <img
                  src={`../assets/${caseItem.img}.png`}
                  alt={caseItem.title}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Cases;
```

Hi guys, im trying to map images from this array object. Everything works fine but the images wont load, on console it says "Not found" but the path of the images is correct.

Im using Vite.js to run my project, i dont know if thats the problem.

Hope you can help me! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem moving /assets folder from src to public folder. Then use the new path and worked.